# Centering Full-screen Responsive Image - Jquery Method

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm referencing CSS Trick's Full Page Background and using their Jquery method that I have working perfectly here: www.oxbowdesigns.com

But, I'm having trouble updating the jquery to center the image instead of staying fixed on the left when there's an overflow.

Below are two images showing what's happening now and what my goal is:

[Current](http://oxbowdesigns.com/images/StackOverflow/Current.jpg)

[Goal](http://oxbowdesigns.com/images/StackOverflow/Goal.jpg)

Here's the code I'm working with:

```js
$(window).load(function() {

  var theWindow = $(window),
    $bg = $("#bg"),
    aspectRatio = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

  function resizeBg() {

    if ((theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio) {
      $bg
        .removeClass()
        .addClass('bgheight');
    } else {
      $bg
        .removeClass()
        .addClass('bgwidth');
    }

  }

  theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");

});
```

```css
#bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.bgwidth {
  width: 100%;
}
.bgheight {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="images/Homepage/HomepageResize2.jpg" id="bg">
```

I've tried using CSS margin:50%; and other CSS techniques with no luck. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: is it possible for you to just change the `<img>` to `<div>` with `background-image`?

Comment: No it's not. I'm also applying this same code to a full-screen slide show that uses img src.

Comment: did your markup looks like this? `<div><img src="..." /></div>`

Answer (score 0):

this code below sweets your needs : this is css method without the need of using js

```
body { 
  background: url(../../images/HomepageResize2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ze RuBuES for your answer. I should of mentioned that it needs to stay with this format because I'm also applying this code to a full-screen slide show that needs the img source in the html.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

I think I've got the ideas wrong last time, when I revisit your link, I realized that the `Script` and `CSS` is wrong, here's the one that should be right

First the `CSS`:

```
body, html {
    overflow: hidden;    // So there is no scrollbar
}
.bgwidth {
    width: 100%;    // No more need to use top:50%
}
.bgheight {
    left: 50%;    // No more need to use height:100%, because you never set the height, so it should always be 100%
}
```

and Second the `Script`:

```
var theWindow = $(window),
    $bg = $("#bg"),
    aspectRatio = $bg.width() / $bg.height();
var imgWidth = $bg.width();
var imgHeight = $bg.height();

function resizeBg() {
    var heightDifference = (theWindow.height() - $bg.height()) / 2;

    if ((theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio) {
        $bg.removeClass().addClass('bgheight');
        $bg.css("margin", heightDifference + "px 0 0 -" + imgWidth / 2 + "px");
    } else {
        $bg.removeClass().addClass('bgwidth');
        $bg.css("margin", heightDifference + "px 0 0 0");
    }
}
theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");
```

Note the difference from before, `imgWidth` and `imgHeight` not divided by 2 anymore, and there's another `var` inside the `resizeBg` function to calculate the height difference between the `window` and `img` divided by 2, then on the `css`, it set the `margin-top` with the `heightDifference` (Because it will always start from the top, so no need to use `top: 50%`), and if it's `bgheight`, it set the `margin-left` too with half of `imgWidth`

So basically it's always `centering` the `image` vertically, then if the `width` is bigger than the window, it will center the `image` horizontally

Here's the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/de2exztz/1/)

### Old Answers

After looking for your website, I see you're using `position: fixed` for the image, in that case, you can use the `left` and `margin` to style your image position

what you need is change the `class` style to this

```
.bgwidth { width: 100%; top: 50%; }        // Center the position vertically
.bgheight { height: 100%; left: 50%; }     // Center the position horizontally
```

then in your script, add some more code

```
function resizeBg() {

    var imgWidth = $bg.width() / 2;
    var imgHeight = $bg.height() / 2;

    if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
        $bg.removeClass().addClass('bgheight');
        $bg.css("margin", "0 0 0 -" + imgWidth + "px");     // margin-left minus half of width
    } else {
        $bg.removeClass().addClass('bgwidth');
        $bg.css("margin", "-" + imgHeight + "px 0 0 0");    // margin-top minus half of height
    }

}
```

what it do is, if class is `bgheight`, you want to center the `image` horizontally, that's why you set the position of the `image` firstly in the center (`left: 50%`), then you set the margin to `0 0 0 x` where `x` is negative half of the `image` width, so it will show the center of the image. The above code isn't tested yet, but you should be able to solve it if there's some code error in `.css`

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/de2exztz/) without the `script`, just think that the `div` is the current window

Comment: Thank you for this Kyojimaru! It's definitely what I'm looking for. I've been working on this most of the day and it's very close to working but not 100%. I'm still having trouble with the margin moving the image too far over at certain screen sizes. I've tried a range of things with the CSS but it's a weird issue that's happening. 

This is as far as I got today: [OxbowDesigns.com](http://oxbowdesigns.com)

If you have any more advice, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks again for getting me this far Kyojimaru!

Comment: PROGRESS! It's so close to working. The problem is the VAR imgWidth and imgHeight are not updating the window.width & .height on resize. I altered your code a little bit:

From:
    var imgWidth = $bg.width() / 2;
    var imgHeight = $bg.height() / 2;
to:
    var imgWidth = $( window ).width() / 2;
    var imgHeight = $( window ).height() / 2; 

I have the code uploaded on http://oxbowdesigns.com. 

Any advice on how to update the VAR on resize?

Comment: @Wing, did you solved the problem already? And what did you mean by `how to update the VAR on resize?`, didn't you trigger the `function` on windows resize?

Comment: Sorry for the delay response - I still haven't got it working yet. Here's a link to a site that has your code added to it [UPDATED CODE SITE](http://oxbowdesigns.com/fullscreen.html) . What I noticed as an issue is the margin isn't changing, it's staying a fixed number based off the image. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you Kyojumaru! I'm going to spend all day tomorrow working on this!

Comment: Here's a link to what's happening with the new code. http://oxbowdesigns.com/fullscreen.html

It works perfectly if you resize the page in horizontal ratios. But when the page size is starting to become vertically tall the page doesn't take up the full height. Also, at 2530 x 1250 window size on load/refresh the picture has a 130px gap on the top. I'm going to  swap out different sized images based on the window width/height and see if that fixes things.

Comment: @Wing, in the current `code`, it won't change the `height` of the `image`, it will change the `width` to `100%` and `height` will changed automatically with the ratio when it's class is `bgwidth`. If it's class is `bgheight`, it will just center the `image` in the `viewport` without changing it's `width` or `height` value. If you don't want to have a gap on top and bottom, you need to add some `code` to check if the `viewport height` is `greater` than the `image height`, then set the `image height` to `viewport height`. Or have a lot more bigger image.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly sorry for the renaming of css and variables. I was working on something for myself and was looking up how to center the image myself. I have figured out a solution and thought I would share it.

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  var windowData = $(window),
    wallpaper = $('#wallpaper'),
    aspectRatio = wallpaper.width() / wallpaper.height();

  function resizeWallpaper() {

    var widthLarger = false;

    if ((windowData.width() / windowData.height()) < aspectRatio) {
      widthLarger = true;
      wallpaper.removeClass().addClass('wallpaperHeight');
    } else {
      widthLarger = false;
      wallpaper.removeClass().addClass('wallpaperWidth');
    }

    var imgWidth = wallpaper.width();
    var imgHeight = wallpaper.height();
    var diff = 0;

    if (widthLarger) {
      if (imgWidth > windowData.width()) {
        diff = (imgWidth - windowData.width()) / 2;
      }
      wallpaper.css("margin", "0 0 0 -" + diff + "px");
    } else {
      if (imgHeight > windowData.height()) {
        diff = (imgHeight - windowData.height()) / 2;
      }
      wallpaper.css("margin", "-" + diff + "px 0 0 0");
    }
  }

  $(window).resize(resizeWallpaper).trigger("resize");

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wallpaper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wallpaperWidth {
  width: 100%;
}

.wallpaperHeight {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <img id="wallpaper" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/kartandtinki1_free-wallpaper_13.jpg">

</body>

</html>
```